# ReSharper will not build multiple projects when debugging

Tags: visual-studio-2015, resharper

I am using Visual Studio 2015 update 3 and have a solution full of independent API projects. Some time recently, it stopped building all the projects under a multi-project solution when start Debug.

All projects are set to Always Build in the Resharper "Build & Run" settings.

Multiple Startup Projects is selected and the "Build" option is selected on all projects under Configuration manager.

However, only one project will build. That is whatever project is at the top of the Configuration Manager list. I can move a different project to the top of that list to make it the project that builds.

The only way I can get multiple projects to run is to make the top Configuration Manager project depend on them.

I've uninstalled and reinstalled VS and Resharper and reset both to default settings and have had no luck.

Any ideas what the problem might be? I've never had to set all the projects to depend on each other for them to all build before.

Windows 10 Pro FWIW

**Updates**

- [Projects and Solutions > Build and Run settings Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WywE7.png)
- manually executing an MSBUILD command against the SLN file builds all projects without issue.
- Still no luck with this but I have, at least, confirmed that it is a ReSharper Build issue. VS Build is building all of the projects as it should. I can, at least, use VS Build until I can figure out what's going on with ReSharper Build.

Comment: Does the Output window also not include the info about other API projects? Does it work without ReSharper? Does IIS show only one of the projects as being built?

Comment: Correct. The output window isn't showing nay build information. I uninstalled Resharper last night and was still not able to build multiple projects. I;m not entirely sure what you mean about IIS though (using express). The projects are there and accessible in IIS express, I just have to manually build them all to get the changes there.

Comment: Output window has a combobox saying 'Show output from' - have you set it to 'Build'?

Comment: Yes. it automatically changes to Build when I start debugging. The only thing it outputs is "Build started at XX:XX:XX" and then "Build Completed in 00:00:04:.139"

Comment: Have a look here and set more verbose mode of output https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/msbuild/2005/09/28/cranking-up-the-build-verbosity-in-the-ide/

Comment: Thanks. It was set to minimal, i tried detailed and diagnostic but it made no difference (assuming because build isn't running on any projects?). In fact, the Build output is empty even if I build the entire solution or single projects manually. https://i.stack.imgur.com/WywE7.png

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue as you, except with Visual Studio 2017. Did you ever find a solution?  Was a ticket created with JetBrains?

Comment: I reported the bug to JetBrains https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-465538

Comment: Sorry. Bradley... still no luck for me. I stopped using Resharper build and went back to to VS build (which works... just not preferable)

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you have proper 'Start' Action selected for the projects you want? (The question only says you have Multiple Startup Projects)
[image]

Comment: Thanks but, yes, all of the projects are set to "Start" under startup projects.